# How does assembly subq set flags for a branch like JLE? Which register has to be greater for it to jump?

Tags: assembly, x86, att

If we do something like:

```
subq %rbx, rax
jle somewhere
```

Does this mean jump if rbx is less than or equal to rax or rbx is greater than or equal to rax?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably confused by the AT&T syntax.
In Intel syntax these two instructions would look like

```
sub rax, rbx      ; subq %rbx, rax
jle somewhere     ; Jump if LESS-OR-EQUAL
```

One major advantage of the Intel notation is, that you can easily derive the comparison operators. In this case this would look like

```
IF rax <= rbx     ; IF rax LESS-OR-EQUAL rbx    
THEN JUMP target  ; DO THE JUMP IF YES
```

This can be used as a rule of thumb.
So the conditional JUMP `Jcc` is taken if the previous condition is `TRUE`.